# Should Stack Overflow support video upload?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

Do you think it's good to have a video upload feature in Stack Overflow or in the entire Stack Exchange? Imagine the benefit if the one who's asking the question could not just read the answers but also watch a short footage on how to solve the problem rather than redirecting to a certain website like YouTube or Channel 9. Just a thought.

Comment: Even if they did, it would *still* rely on an external service like YouTube or Channel9. You do realize they use Imgur for image uploads, right? They don't host the stuff themselves.

Comment: This would be excellent, I often like to produce videos providing a more in-depth answer than is sometimes possible as text https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers

Comment: Because we want people posting *answers*, rather than videos.

Comment: (Videos aren’t really an efficient means of communication. Or even an effective one for some people.)

Comment: Judging by the standard of some answers we see here a video presentation would be unwatchable. Life's too short.

Comment: Very surprised to see all the down votes on this and especially some of the video answers that just say "No" in a cartoon. There are accessibility concerns with video answers but instead of snarky answers or comments I would rather see explanations.

Answer (score 17):

#### [No](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hwz7YN1AQmQ)

Comment: *Please include some relevant info from this link that helps answer the question.  Otherwise, if the link dies, this answer will become obsolete.*

Comment: @Jamal: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v6BL6QvKljo

Comment: *Where's my [meta-tag:status-declined] automatic video upload feature?*