# Embeding YouTube videos

Tags: feature-request

I might get tons of down-votes for this, like this [question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256410/why-is-it-that-stackoverflow-doesnt-support-video-upload) but I wish there was a way to embed YouTube videos in questions. It makes explaining problems much easier. For example I [asked a question with video here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24464674/forcing-subview-refresh-layout-in-ios-autolayout).

I know there is a big chance of abuse but allowing it just for user with higher repetition it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: A question should be able to stand on its own as much as possible, without external references and resources. I say as much as possible because, of course, sometimes you just need to *show* people what your problem is - and you have. That rare need, however, doesn't warrant allowing and developing the feature to embed videos, in my opinion. =)

Comment: There are some excellent GIF animation recorders out there. Those make for great demos, and can be uploaded to the SE imgur site to boot.

Comment: @MartijnPieters GIFs are very inefficient

Comment: @KatjaChristiansen I'm not asking for **uploading** support. I'm asking foe **embeding**. Like Imgur for images.

Comment: @J.Steen You can factor out the cost of developing, since it's already implemented and enabled on some sites.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Low quality, outrageous bandwidth usage, inefficient decoding -- what's not to love about GIF? (Maybe Stack Exchange could ditch Imgur and partner with something like Gyfcat instead, and help kill the format.)

Comment: I'm fully aware of the drawbacks. I was merely pointing out there is another way to include a demo.

Comment: @JeremyBanks True, true. Still. =)

Comment: I cannot use youtube at work. Heck, there is not even sound in my computer at work. There is also no reason why I would need either of those. I also don't want to listen to a 6 minute video where someone doesn't come to the point. If someone posts a 6 minute wall of text, I can scan through the answer and find what I am looking for. Video is not a good medium to transfer knowledge about how to solve a problem. In a very limited amount of cases, one can use a set of screenshots instead that illustrate the answer. Unlike video, this also allows easy skipping to step 5 if step 1-4 are trivial.

Answer (score 13):

Some sites do allow YouTube embeds, such as [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), due to the nature of the subject matter. Video games are, well, video, so it makes sense to be able to embed things like video walkthroughs.

The issue here is that Stack Overflow questions by nature involve code, which is most definitely text and not video. And we'd very much rather have raw text content than video, especially if the videos are hosted elsewhere.

You can still link to a video if it's really necessary, but the opportunities to link to videos for legitimate reasons are so few and far between that I just can't make a case for enabling video embedding here.

Comment: ok, this is a legitimate answer to question I had. Now someone please explain me where those down-votes are coming from? Did I ask a bad question?!

Comment: @Mohsen You posted a feature request.  Feature requests use the voting buttons for, "I dis/agree".  As you can see, many users don't want this functionality here at SO.  Generally, I agree with that, as videos add a ton of cruft to programming questions.  They're massive wastes of time, compared to straight text.

Comment: @fbueckert makes sense. In this context down votes doesn't mean bad question