# Thank you for enabling YouTube embedding!

Tags: bug, status-completed, revision-history

After Dark Mode I think this was [the second most sought after feature request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261834/embeding-youtube-videos). Just link to a YouTube video and have your question answered or gather 6 to 8 upvotes on your video only answer. This makes Stack Overflow so much better.

It is a bit sad that it is only enabled so far on the [revision history](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/256412/revisions) here on MSO:

[image]

Can you please take the appropriate action?

Comment: I was tempted to create the [meta-tag:youtube]  tag ...

Comment: How exactly would youtube videos ever be useful for SO? It's bad enough that we have to suffer the endless "pictures of code" questions. Next up, videos of code.

Comment: It's May 13th. Not April 1st.

Comment: @Scratte I had to double-check too.

Comment: The irony-force is strong with this one.

Comment: It's so you can more easily send them screaming videos of how the **next** changes will be making you feel ;)

Comment: @Patrice not as good as a video, but [here is a wiki article that summarizes my view](https://en.uncyclopedia.co/wiki/AAAAAAAAA!)

Comment: that is one of the most horrible ideas i ever heard for this side

Comment: Really nice! Now, if I have a long section of code, I can just share a video of me scrolling through it, while previously I had to take multiple pictures and stitch them together.

Comment: Eeeek!!.... please don't scare me like that!

Comment: Please edit this to say it's sarcastic & state your actual point clearly, the post is going to be misinterpreted by many.

Comment: @philipxy why misinterpreting? We are all happy with this new feature. I already start recoridng my first canonical answer ...

Comment: People should practice decoding sarcasm (if not native) by watching [some TechLead videos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ODaq-JEiIKg&lc=UgyNuHu1LzJ3u2BRsVh4AaABAg).

Comment: It is however common knowledge that sarcasm in written text doesn't work very well.

Comment: @Cerbrus I made a video but it didn't embed hence the report ... ;)

Comment: If the [tag:status-review] now leads to YT embedding being enabled everywhere I apologize upfront .... and take the eternal blame ...

Comment: @rene Video killed the programming star? I'm gonna have to start posting answers here in video selfie-format, representing myself reading the source code aloud: "Include standard i o dot h. Int main void". Or better yet, an animated video of Mario reading the MOS 6502 assembler source code of Super Mario Bros aloud.

Comment: @Catija You got my extra imaginary mental points for this edit :) My next youtube video will show a slowmotion update of the post.

Comment: @rene If that happens, I will be a very sad person and Nick will likely be very angry. If it makes you feel better, I added a note to the Trello card this became giving a translation of the post.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

YouTube embedding on MSO is now deactivated (it had been on there, but never on for SO).