# HTML Embedding in answers

Tags: feature-request

In certain cases, embedding a tool in the HTML of an answer would be extremely helpful, though this is not possible on Stack Overflow currently. For instance, it would be really nice to be able to embed a weather widget that we can't get to work right in a question, or embed in an answer a tool we recommend to the OP. This would also help with embedding YouTube videos in answers or questions, which would enable putting in helpful video explanations or tutorials useful to an OP, as well as the ability to put in videos of a problem occurring with the OP's app right into the question.

In addition, the ability to embed something into an answer (embedding-in-website style) would have uses beyond Stack Overflow. One case of this I came across was in the English Stack Exchange, specifically Helmar's answer to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/337769/is-it-awkward-to-call-a-wound-heavy). Helmar was using non-enlargeable, less-than-clear screenshot of a Google NGram graph to show word usage, which would have looked far nicer with an interactive embedded NGram chart, code for which Google gives you right next to said chart.

Embedding videos and tools (like Google NGram charts or other widgets) right into questions/answers would certainly help a variety of users in a wide swath of use cases.

Comment: Please no! I can see where this would end up :-P ...

Comment: For the YouTube part this is [status-declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256410/should-stack-overflow-support-video-upload)

Comment: so... we have issues with newbies posting images of their code/error messages. PLEASE NO VIDEOS, PLEASE. I will lose my mind if I have to debug from a VIDEO...

Comment: but .... @Patrice ... I use my phone to make the video of the screen ... sorry about the cat in the middle ... and I had to sneeze 3 minutes in which made it a bit shaky at the end but beyond that ... what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: This would create 3rd party dependencies, loads of which would be guaranteed to become unavailable over time, rendering questions and answers useless.

Comment: You might get a bit more support for NGram on English.SE, where it's actually used. Embedded videos have already been enabled for certain sites, like Sci-Fi & Fantasy. You haven't given a compelling reason for Stack Overflow.

Comment: *or embed in an answer a tool we recommend to the OP* Yes, here, download and run my virus.

Comment: @Patrice It would really be for watching what happens when an app opens or an IDE crashes, but I guess it does run the risk of watching code...but isn't that much more effort anyway? No SO newbie would take the effort of posting a video!

Comment: @Laurel Thanks, I might head over there...

Comment: @Will only from certain permitted sites?

Comment: @JohnRamos oh I get your intent. I'm just saying that, right now, we have enough people misusing pictures... let's not make it easy to misuse videos... (and, you'd honestly be surprised at how people would try to bypass filters/quality standards with video... :/). I mean, it's easier for me to C&P a stack trace than screenshot it. Yet we see the opposite often

Comment: @rene where you able to film it in portrait mode for the best use of the screen?

Comment: @JoeW Niceeee ;).

Comment: @JoeW I keep confusing the front and the back camera ... I have 4 minutes worth of video of my own nostrils ... does that count as *portrait mode* or do we mean something else with that?

Comment: There are lot many fiddle sites to support that, why we need all that stuff with question answer, only code and technical questions are getting piled up daily in thousands. I am worried that this one of the best medium, but will get ruined if that happens here..

Answer (score 16):

**Please no!**

Questions and answers should be self-contained. All relevant information should be included in the post itself. A notable exception being screenshots, which are hosted on [Imgur](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imgur). Allowing inclusion of third-party content will cause questions and answers to stop working when that third-party website is removed. Furthermore, if a problem can not be described using a few paragraphs of text, it is likely too broad. Having a video describing the problem does not help with this.

What is worse is that I can currently trust Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) to be SFW and malware/virus free. When we allow arbitrary content to be included in posts this is no longer true. As such I have to avoid using Stack Overflow (and other Stack Exchange sites) at work. I don't see why this would be helpful in any way.

Comment: Don't forget to mention the search-ability of non-text content. This would change the SE sites to be only helpful for the Op but not for future visitors ....

Comment: @Sumurai8 I certainly see your point about SO being malware/virus free, but isn't Imgur more likely to be shut down/Imgur content to be removed than a YouTube video or NGram chart?

Comment: @rene Very true, thanks.

Comment: @John Stack Exchange has a deal with Imgur. I wouldn't be surprised if the deal contains a clause about Imgur turning over all images if they go out of business

Comment: @Pekka웃 Didn't know that, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can already embed HTML in answers. It's called "Stack snippets".

```html
<h1>Hi!</h1>
<p>I am</p>
<ul>
  <li>embeded
    <ul>
      <li>HTML</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```